# Using Nullable Reference Types in F#

Tags: c#, f#, nullable-reference-types

In F#, if you are interoperating with another .NET language, or if you using the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute, a reference type can be `null`. The example that comes to mind right away are strings:

```ml
let str: string = null
```

But with C# 8 and dotnet core 3, we can opt in to [Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). I would have to write the above code in C# like:

```cs
string? str = null;
```

Is there a way to also opt in to Nullable Reference Types in F# so that types defined in other languages cannot be `null`, and if they could be, write them as a Nullable Reference like:

```ml
let str: string = null // error cannot do this
let str: string? = null
```

I'm aware that we can convert types that might be expected to be `null` by using Options:

```ml
let str : string = null
let strOpt = Option.ofObj str
```

My question is: Is there away that makes it *impossible* to make a reference type `null`, like `string`, without explicitly declaring it to be nullable in F#?

Comment: You actually don't need .NET Core just C# 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/04/FSharp-Nulls/,

> "F# currently supports several versions of nullability. First there are normal .NET
> reference types. Today there is no way to unequivocally inform the compiler if a
> specific reference type variable is nullable or not, so their use in F# is discouraged."

> "The preferred alternative is Option. Also known as a “maybe” type, this is a type-
> safe way to express the concept of nullability. When used with idiomatic F# code, you
> can only read the value after checking to see if it is non-null (not “none” in F#
> parlance). This is usually done via pattern matching."

However, the desire that there would be a clean way to interop with these ? annotations is recognized by the F# team, and a proposal for nullable reference types can be found [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1060-nullable-reference-types.md). As of today, the proposal is "Approved in principle" but no prototype implementation yet exists.